# Problem with an array of pointers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, mfc, operator-overloading

**Language:** C++, MFC

**Problem:** I am attempting to pass a function some pointers to variables that are contained within an array, but the compiler doesn't seem to agree with how I'm doing it. Here is my code:

*Header File:*

```
CString m_strTop;
CString m_strLeft;
CString m_strRight;
CString m_strBottom;

CString *var[4];
```

*Source File:*
**Constructor()**

```
CString *var[4] = {
  &m_strTop
, &m_strLeft
, &m_strRight
, &m_strBottom
};
```

*Source File:*
**DoDataExchange()**

```
void FSC_3DPersp::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   CSAPrefsSubDlg::DoDataExchange(pDX);

   for(int i = 2001, j = 0; i <= 2004, j < 4; i++, j++)
   {
       DDX_Text(pDX, i, &var[j]); // 'i' is the ID of the textbox
   }
}
```

**-- What DDX_Text expects --**

```
void AFXAPI DDX_Text(
   CDataExchange* pDX,
   int nIDC,
   CString& value 
);
```

---

I wanted to do my DataExchange this way because in several of my files, I have upwards of 75 variables, and using a loop significantly condenses the code, and simplifies things.

I know that the problem I'm having is that I'm just feeding DDX_Text the wrong parameters, but I know that it takes CStrings. However, I'm pretty sure I'm not referencing them correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

~ Jon

Comment: I fixed the dereferencing error, but now my program crashes when the code reaches the for loop. I receive the following error: "Access violation reading location 0x000000a3." Perhaps my indices are incorrect? I'm not sure what else it could be...

Comment: You have dialogs with 75 controls? What are you really trying to accomplish? That for loop may raise eyebrows as does a string representation of CRect to me.

Comment: Apparently you are not compiling with warnings enabled. Any decent compiler will tell you that you have the syntax wrong if you ask it to do so.

Comment: I'm basically creating a preferences dialog for a much larger application. One of my preference dialog pages has a large table that the user needs to fill in with values. I just counted and I exaggerated a bit earlier...there are 54 CEdit's on my largest dialog preference screen, not 75.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
DDX_Text(pDX, i, &var[j]);
```

use

```
DDX_Text(pDX, i, *(var[j]));
```

As you already have a level of indirection there.

About this:

```
for(int i = 2001, j = 0; i <= 2004, j < 4; i++, j++)
```

I'm not sure if you are aware that the condition you set there will mean the right one, because that's how comma operator works. You should either leave the left one out as it will never get to be false when the `j < 4` expression is right to it, or use the && operator to be more clear.

I assume you use Visual Studio to do MFC programming, so I suggest set a breakpoint on that line and make sure that your array is initialized correctly. If it is, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: This compiles my code, but now it crashes when the code reaches this point. I receive the following error: "Access violation reading location 0x000000a3." Perhaps my indices are incorrect?

Comment: Good catch, Tamas. That definitely saved me for the future, but it's still crashing for some reason.

Comment: Did my answer help locating the problem?

Comment: Yes, I was able to hone in to exactly where it is failing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
DDX_Text(pDX, i, &var[j]); // 'i' is the ID of the textbox
```

should be

```
DDX_Text(pDX, i, *var[j]); // 'i' is the ID of the textbox
```

Although, looking at your for-loop, and your indices `i` and `j`, I am unsure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This compiles my code, but now it crashes when the code reaches this point. I receive the following error: "Access violation reading location 0x000000a3." Perhaps my indices are incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [dereference](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) the CString pointer:

```
DDX_Text(pDX, i, *var[j])
```

Comment: This compiles my code, but now it crashes when the code reaches this point. I receive the following error: "Access violation reading location 0x000000a3." Perhaps my indices are incorrect?

Comment: @Jon: What is your loop suppose to do? right now it will only loop between the values i: 2001 - 2004 and j: 0 - 3?

Comment: My mistake...I actually simplified my code to post here. I must have forgotten to change the numbers. It's supposed to initialize a data exchange between the textboxes (using the numbered IDs beginning at 2001) and the variables to store them (the variables in the array).

Answer (score 1):

`DDX_Text(pDX, i, &var[j]);` is sending the address of a pointer, a CString **.

Your DDX_Text function is asking for a reference to the value.

Try `DDX_Text(pDX, i, *var[j]);` instead.

Comment: This compiles my code, but now it crashes when the code reaches this point. I receive the following error: "Access violation reading location 0x000000a3." Perhaps my indices are incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

`DDX_Text` expects a reference to `CString`. However, `&var[j]` yields a pointer (`CString**`). You should call it with `*var[j]` (dereference the pointer) - i.e. `DDX_Text(pDX, i, *var[j]);`.

edit:
Your loop probably does not do what you expect. The `for`-loop condition (`i <= 2010, j < 4`), compares `i` to 2010, throws the result away, compares `j` to 4 and uses that result. If you want to combine conditions, use `&&` (logical AND), `||` (logical OR) or `!` (logical NOT).

However, the indices seem to be alright.

Comment: This compiles my code, but now it crashes when the code reaches this point. I receive the following error: "Access violation reading location 0x000000a3." Perhaps my indices are incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
DDX_Text(pDX, i, &var[j]);
```

use

```
DDX_Text(pDX, i, var[j]);
```

Do not use address-of (`&var[j]`) or dereference (`*var[j]`). Just use `var[j]`.